# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with chi-squared data

Tags: r, statistics

I am having hard time to make `ks.test` work with chi-squared distributed data:

```
> chi10 <- rchisq(200,10) 
> ks.test(chi10, dchisq, df=10)


    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  chi10 

D = 0.9983, p-value < 2.2e-16

alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

It looks like it does not recognize this data as `chisq`. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

From `?ks.test` I learn, that the second parameter is "either a numeric vector of data values, or a character string naming a cumulative distribution function or an actual **cumulative** distribution function such as pnorm. Only continuous CDFs are valid."

```
set.seed(123456)
chi10<-rchisq(200,10)

ks.test(chi10,pchisq,df=10)

#One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

#data:  chi10 
#D = 0.0518, p-value = 0.6576
#alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have no idea why I put dchisq instead of pchisq!